# Make regexp shorter

Tags: ruby, regex, simplification

I have the following text: `var avarb avar var varb var`. What I want to do is to extract only "direct" `var` occurrences. The above string contains 3 of them.

While playing with [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/) I made up the following Regexp: `/\A(var)|\s(var)\s|(var)\z/`. 
Is there a way to simplify it, in order to use `var` substring in regexp only once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one using word boundaries:

```
 /\bvar\b/
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use Alexanders version or

```
/(^|\s)(var)($|\s)/       # or:
/(?:^|\s)(var)(?:$|\s)/   # (?: ) will prevent capturing
```

Comment: Thanks for "prevent capturing", didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

`/\s+(var)\+/` would seem sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use lookaheads and lookbehinds:

```
/(?<=^|\s)(var)(?=$|\s)/
```